# Instance ID in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-play-services

Which library should be integrated in my project in order to use the Instance ID API in my iOS/Swift app?

This [page about Instance ID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/) shows how to implement such API, but gives no indication of the library to import....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're supposed to use CocoaPods to install it.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/GGLInstanceID

Comment: [I typed `GGLInstanceID` into Google.](https://www.google.com/search?q=GGLInstanceID)